# How can I check for the presence of adb in an environment variable in a pretinstall or postinstall script for osx?

Tags: macos, adb, pkgbuild

i want to check if adb is already set on variable path before to do an export like
`export PATH=$PATH:~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/` in the installation of the package.

i try with a condition like that

```
if ! command -v ADB &> /dev/null
then
    echo "ADB could not be found"> /tmp/my_postinstall.log
else
    echo "ADB is found"> /tmp/my_postinstall.log
fi
```

it's working in the terminal, but not the postinstall script (which is executable)

what i have forgotten?

thanks

Comment: It might be worth printing out the `$PATH` during the postinstall script and seeing if that differs from the `$PATH` you have in the terminal; if so that might explain your issue.  If not... my suggestions would be to A) consider whether the search is case-sensitive in one instance but not the other, B)  see if you get different results when switching on the result of a `which ADB` call in your script, or c) consider more monotonously/manually searching for adb in the user's `$PATH`

Comment: @eckenrod you are right, my `$PATH` doesn't return the same thing. the postinstall return `/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec` when my terminal return `
/anaconda3/bin:
/Users/fabrice/Library/Android/sdk//tools:
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:
/Users/fabrice/Library/Android/sdk//platform-tools:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin: ...
' why $PATH returns different things

Comment: In the postinstall the $PATH seems to ignore the ~/.bash_profile but i don't know why.

Comment: The script must not run in the user's context then. In that case you should manually update your `$PATH` before doing the search for adb, either via copying and pasting the `$PATH` update code from your `~/.bash_profile` into the postinstall script, or adding the following line to the postinstall script: `source /Users/username/.bash_profile` which should have the same effect.

Comment: @eckenrod **Your solution is working!** I used `source  ~/.bash_profile` in the postinstall script. But as i'm beginner on stackoverflow, it seems i can't accept your answer for now because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

The postinstall script does not run in any user context, and therefore doesn't inherit a given user's `$PATH`. Running `source /Users/username/.bash_profile` will update the `$PATH` your script sees to match that of the user's you want to check.